# Kali-linux default password for live session

Tags: kali-linux, login, password, live-usb

I tried to install kali through Unetbootin but it failed. After that, I tried to go on live one, but without setting any password. It asked for that as default. I entered `root` as username but don't know the password. What it could be?

Answer (score 3):

The default password for `root` user is `toor`. See this https://docs.kali.org/introduction/kali-linux-default-passwords